# A question on the "intermediate value property" for disconnected sets!

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

We know that a continuous function on a connected space satisfies the Intermediate value property. Let $\mathbb{R}^+\times Z_{\alpha}=X_{\alpha}$, where $$Z_{\alpha}=\{\alpha+n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$ for every $\alpha \in (0,1]$. Let $\mathbb{R}^+$ denote the set of positive real numbers. Let $f$ be a function $$f: X_{\alpha}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+,$$ which is continuous for every $\alpha \in (0,1]$.

Note that $\bigcup_{\alpha} X_{\alpha}=\mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}^+$, which is connected. I am wondering if $f$ will satisfy the intermediate value property on  $\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+$ or $X_{\alpha}?$

Any suggestion/tip is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the domain of $f$ is $X_{\alpha}$ then $f$ is not one function but  a family of functions.

Comment: Perhaps you intend $f: \bigcup_{\alpha} X_{\alpha} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that each restriction $f \rvert_{X_{\alpha}} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be any function from $(0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^{+}$ and define $f(t,s+n)=g(s)$. This function is  a constant on each $X_{\alpha}$ so it is continuous there. But $f$ does not have IVP if $g$ does not have IVP.